# How to extend a Bootstrap input on click?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've made a search bar in my navbar, but I would like that when the input is clicked, it extends himself to his normal size. I think I have to use some JavaScript but I don't know how do that.

Below follows my code:

```
<form action="" method="" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
       <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
      </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how you do it in jquery.

```
$("input.form-control").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("changeStyle");
});

// the css
.changeStyle
{
    width:300px; //normal size
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to change input width on click event, use jQuery Animate.

You will need to change width property on input click event.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.large-input {
    width: 300px; /* whatever you want */
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
       <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search-input" placeholder="Rechercher">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
      </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS** using jQuery

```
$("#search-input").focus(function(event) { $(event.target).addClass('large-input'); }); 
$("#search-input").blur(function(event) { $(event.target).removeClass('large-input'); });
```